# Deploy Java Application with Embedded Derby Database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, netbeans-8

Am developing a java desktop application using Netbeans 1.8 IDE, the application will use embedded derby database to store data. The connection to the derby database is by the following.

```
 final String host = "jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\Faisal\\.netbeans- 
 derby\\Wa_Poly";
 final String uName = "APP";
 final String uPass = "12345";
```

the following code snippet is used to connect  to the database.

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass)) {
        try (Statement pstm = 
          con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,  
          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {
            try (ResultSet rslt = pstm.executeQuery(newRowSQL + sortby)) {
                bd = getData(rslt);
            }
```

to deploy the application  , I added the database to the dist folder generated by the Netbeans.
But any time I run the application , it is not able to connect to the Wa_Poly database 
Any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Does it run from IDE?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new database? Or open an existing one? To create a new database, you can specify ";create=true" when you call DriverManager.getConnection().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In host var you specified different path than to your dist folder. If you put your db to your dist folder, it should be sufficient to have something like this

```
final String host = "jdbc:derby:Wa_Poly";
```

Do you load JDBC driver properly?

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

Note that for further investigation it would be good to provide more code.