# Is there a way to create Installer for Java App with Derby DB

Tags: java, windows-installer, database-connection, derby

my question is simple. I have Java App Project in NetBeans. My project use Derby DB and database was created via NetBeans in NetBeans.

I know how to integrate a Java DB database into a NetBeans Platform application but that will take much more time and practicaly I will need to create new NetBeans Platform and do everything from begging.

My question is there a posibility to create Installer that will include my existing database?! thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question specifically about an "installer"? Or about how to embed a Derby database into your application? You can find lots of help for the latter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393385/setting-up-an-embedded-derby-database-in-a-standalone-java-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688162/java-standalone-app-with-jpa-hibernate-or-similar-and-apache-derby-embedded?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620182/deploy-java-application-with-embedded-derby-database?rq=1

Comment: Thanks anyway! I found solution.... Best solution is to create functions for creating table in app , when I create table in my project everything is fine. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! Best way is to create methods for creating tables,inputing values...

SOLVED